# Is there a nice way to display big nested tables?

Tags: list-manipulation, slideshows

I have a really big nested table. I can copy my code here if you wish, that is not a problem, but it will be a lot of it and I am not sure if it makes sense.
the end expression is this

```
final = Table[{j, 
    Table[{lengthall[[i]], optimumfall[[j, i]], narisane[[j]]}, {i, 1,
       n - 4 + m, 1}]}, {j, 1, cellnumber, 1}];
```

for `cellnumber=25` and `n-4+m=36`. So it's probably not the smallest table you have ever seen.

However, I have to present this table to people that have no idea what Mathematica is or does. So it has to look good (visually - something like Latex or Excel does) and I have no idea how to do it. I tried with `Grid`, but I am not really satisfied. Check here (link) http://www4.slikomat.com/13/0720/oix-Captur.png .
So, are there any other possibilities? Maybe some strange `Export` protocol? Or yeah, anything should work. I have to warn you though, in the table `final` there are not only numbers (as seen on the attached printscreen), but also some plots.

Comment: How does `final//MatrixForm` look? Or `final//TableForm`?

Comment: This kind of problems are usually thought the other way around: you first design what you want to see and THEN you try to do it :)

Comment: You already asked 15 questions but voted only once. Please try to vote more, see below for some advice

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Export to Excel? You say you like it formatting.

Comment: @N.J.Evans They work (http://www4.slikomat.com/13/0720/ohc-Captur.png) but as m_goldberg said, I would like to do some formatting because if I show table like that in public, people would ask if I am on drugs. :)

Comment: @belisarius : yes, I did actually, and I didn't expect problems here. But looks like I will have to rethink that.

Comment: I don't see any nesting in your table.  It looks like a simple table of graphs with an ID  and what appears to be an average value.   Are you seriously planning to show each of these graphs to your audience without putting them to sleep?

Comment: You might also consider actually placing the various numbers as labels on the plots. That should probably be a new question if you want to go there though.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to export the data into an .txt or .dat file, so that it would look something like this http://www4.slikomat.com/13/0721/ds-Captur.png where the first column is index j from my original post, the second goes from 1 to 36 as I said and any other columns are calculations that I did...?

Comment: For example like the TableForm does it, as @N.J.Evans suggested: http://www4.slikomat.com/13/0721/1kn-Captur.png but in a .dat file?

Comment: this last bit is really a new question, if you want that specific structure output to an ascii file. (Obviously you are no longer working with plots..?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.  Also study this to learn how to create a minimal working example:

```
mwe = Table[{j, Table[RandomInteger[10, 3], {i, 1, 36, 1}]}, {j, 1, 25}];
Row[Column[{#[[1]], MatrixForm@#[[2]]} , Center ] & /@ mwe]
```

showing here a smaller version:

[image]

Comment: This is actually a lot better than what the programme does by default. This might actually work. And I thought about @David Carraher comment on the OP - he is right. So I think I can mark that as answered, I am pretty satisfied with the looks of that.